# Manipulate object to make different format

Tags: javascript, jquery

sorry for the stupid question but I am also looking for a nice solution for this problem:

I have this object

```
var obj = {
    "brand[]" : [1,2,3],
    "model[]" : [1,2,3],
    "varqnt[]" : [1,2,3]
}
```

Now what I want is to make a new object/array ( i don't think it matters for now ) from it which should be

```
var newObj = {
    'row-1': {
        brand[] : 1,
        model[] : 1,
        varqnt[] : 1
    },
    'row-2': {
        brand[] : 2,
        model[] : 2,
        varqnt[] : 2
    },
    'row-3': {
        brand[] : 3,
        model[] : 3,
        varqnt[] : 3
    }
}
```

The tricky part is that 'brand[]', 'model[]', 'varqnt[]' might not all be there.

I will try to explain a bit more...
basically the first object is comming from url params, of 2 select boxes and 1 input, but since I use the same form in different "places" this varqnt[] ( the input ) might not be presented.

I am not sure if anyone will understand me.. but english is not mother's language as an excuse :P

Thanks, and if I wrote something totaly unclear sorry :(

Comment: This doesn't really have much to do with jquery.

Comment: i added it, because if someone is writing a solution, he can show the example using jquery, since I am using it

Comment: Can you fix initial object, because not it's syntactically invalid.

Comment: ah yeah, sorry. Copy / paste from console, never goes well :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with two loops. For example:

```js
var obj = {
    "brand[]":  [12, 2,  3],
    "model[]":  [1,  2,  32],
    "varqnt[]": [1,  21, 3]
};

var newObj = {};
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    obj[key].forEach(function(el, i) {
        if (typeof newObj['row-' + i] == "undefined") {
            newObj['row-' + i] = {};
        }
        newObj['row-' + i][key] = el;
    });
});


alert(JSON.stringify(newObj, null, 4));
```

Comment: now this is what i call a master.
Own you a beer man, thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

Well you can do something like this and access each element in your object

```
var newObj = {};
for (data in obj){
console.log(obj[data])
}
```